# Calculate percentage of each category in each group in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
Group    Category    Freq
1       A           2
1       B           3
1       C           5
2       A           3
2       B           1
2       C           6
```

I want to introduce a fourth column which calculates the percentage of each category inside each group.

```
Group    Category    Freq       % (calculated per group, for categories)
    1       A           2       20
    1       B           3       30
    1       C           5       50
    2       A           5       25
    2       B           1       5
    2       C           14      70
```

I tried the following (No success)

```
as.data.frame(prop.table(table(myDF),1)*100)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710368/calculate-percentage-for-each-time-series-observations-per-group-in-r

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Category = c(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]), Freq = c(2, 3, 5, 5, 1, 14))
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(proc = (Freq/sum(Freq) * 100))
```

Comment: How is this different from the solution I provided earlier?

Comment: I worked at the same time as you did, haven't seen your post before sending my answer: moreover, my example is directly repeatable as it contains data

Comment: It throws me following error

    `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: this worked for me

`df$percentage = signif(100*with(df, ave(Freq, Group, FUN=function(x) x/sum(x))),4)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(Percent = 100*Freq/sum(Freq))
```

Comment: As I wrote, the difference was that I had a data frame that made the example reapeatable directly. @akrun you are a very expirienced user here, shouldn't you vote to close down as it was rather simple question? This is my conclusion after a while

Comment: @Mateusz1981  The OP already provided the dataset in his post.  So, I didn't thought to include an example again in my post.  Anyway, it is closed as dupe.